# What does it mean when an account is suspended due to plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I stumbled upon a user who seems to have been suspended for plagiarism:

[image: "This account is temporarily suspended for plagiarism. The suspension period ends in 7 days."]

What is plagiarism and why can it get an account suspended?

Comment: @Rob - thanks for the edit. I destroyed the original revision with the user detail.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i just want to show example :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) is the copying of content (text, images etc...) without attribution.

The user seems to have copied the contents of their answers from elsewhere without saying so.

Wikipedia says this:

> Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "purloining and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions," and the representation of them as one's own original work.

Comment: Thank @Oded, stackoverflow should bring it to `about` or something else :)

Comment: @RongNK - Plagiarism is an easy word to search for and most people instinctively know that copying stuff is not right.

Comment: I think it can be a note, for example: user come from some country where the attribution isn't important, user can be come Plagiarism :)

Comment: @RongNK - Can you give me an example of such a country?

Comment: shame, my country, `without attribution` is commonly...

Comment: @RongNK - And yet, the example you showed was from a country where attribution requirements are well known... Regardless, though many other sites on the Internet don't seem to care, we do.

Comment: @Oded "most people instinctively know that copying stuff is not right." [citation needed] /sigh

Comment: @Yannis - thanks for your contribution to this thread.