# Oops! Something Bad Happened! at timeline with deleted revision

Tags: bug, timeline

The original version of [What does it mean when an account is suspended due to plagiarism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180080/this-account-is-temporarily-suspended-for-plagiarism) contained a user profile in the screenshot, which I've edited out. Afterwards, a SE developer destroyed the revision ([revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/180080/revisions)).

I was wondering if the timeline would show anything useful, so I replaced `/questions/{id}/...` with `/posts/{id}/timeline` (https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/180080/timeline), resulting in [this error page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/180080/timeline):

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened! We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified. Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them. It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, meta.stackoverflow.com.]

(for the record, I'm using Firefox 20.0.1 on Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, apparently.
At least for me, with 10K reputation, there is no issue to access the timeline at present time.